# VBA: Double filter on a sheet, how to filter out data between two certain intervals

Tags: vba, excel

I need the `VBA` code to filter out the alarm logs from a certain time window. Alarms appear and clear out on some objects. I need the script the filter out the alarms between two specified times (e.g those which appeared on/after 1AM AND were cleared by/before 3AM), and copy the filtered data to another sheet. Please refer to the attached image.

***See the given image, which shows the all the alarm logs.***
[image]

Comment: Note that two conditions are to be applied on two different columns. First condition is on the column of 'RaisedTime' and the other is on 'Clear Time'.

Comment: date/time is just a running number. having a filter with `>= 2017-03-04 01:00:00` and one with `<= 2017-03-04 03:00:00` connected by AND will do the job. Best start is, to do it manually while recording as macro. ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel It needs to be variable. Given example is just an illustration, not the actual task (which contains thousands of alarm logs, and I need to loop through different time windows to be defined by variables taking values from some other sheet).

Comment: @DirkReichel Can you show me how to apply filter on two separate columns? if Col1>=X And Col2<=Y then .....

Comment: select headers and hit the "filter" button at the "home" ribbon. then start recording macro (developer ribbon). hit the small arrow for col1 -> date filters -> custom filter. select for the upper left dropdown "is after or equal to" and enter in the upper right window the date/time. also do this for col2 (but select "is before or equal to"). now stop recording the macro. if you look at the code, you will find `Criteria1:= ">=2017-03-04 01:00"`. just hand this over by a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify your data somewhat as no raised and cleared time met your criteria.

```
Option Explicit

Sub betweenTimes()
    With Worksheets("Sheet5")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
            'as hardcoded values
            '.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & Format(Date + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
            '.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="<=" & Format(Date + TimeSerial(3, 0, 0), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
            'as values from I3:J3
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Format(.Parent.Cells(3, "I").Value2, "\>\=yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
            .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=Format(.Parent.Cells(3, "J").Value2, "\<\=yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    Union(.Cells, .Cells(1, "XFD")).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(2, "A")
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]